# fullpage.js - unable to scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

I'm currently work on a wordpress site using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs), but unfortunately i'm not able to use it properly.

Here's the scenario: my website uses polylang so that it can be multilingual, and i've created all the pages and all the menus, the setup fo both polylang and fullpage.js is done properly, but fullpage.js works properly only on the default page (english) and not on the others (french, italian and spanish).

It start to work only if you click on the menu, then seams like it is unlocked and works.

Any idea why?
I'm calling a function when window is loaded to check the current language and then apply fullpage to the target id, like this:

```
var $ = jQuery;

function load_right_language_fullpage() {
    var lang = location.pathname.split("/")[1];

    switch (lang) {
        case 'en':
            console.log("en");
            fullPageSlider_en()
            break;
        case 'it':
            console.log("it");
            fullPageSlider_it()
            break;
        case 'es':
            console.log("es");
            fullPageSlider_es()
            break;
        case 'fr':
            console.log("fr");
            fullPageSlider_fr()
            break;
    }
}
function fullPageSlider_en() {
    $('#menu-item-79').attr('data-menuanchor', 'biography');
    $('#menu-item-80').attr('data-menuanchor', 'references');
    $('#menu-item-81').attr('data-menuanchor', 'prices');
    $('#menu-item-82').attr('data-menuanchor', 'contacts');
    $('#fullpage-en').fullpage({
        menu: '#site-navigation',
        anchors: ['home', 'biography', 'references', 'prices', 'contacts']
    });
};
function fullPageSlider_fr() {
    $('#menu-item-87').attr('data-menuanchor', 'biographie');
    $('#menu-item-88').attr('data-menuanchor', 'références');
    $('#menu-item-89').attr('data-menuanchor', 'prix');
    $('#menu-item-90').attr('data-menuanchor', 'contacts');
    $('#fullpage-fr').fullpage({
        menu: '#site-navigation',
        anchors: ['home', 'biographie', 'références', 'prix', 'contacts']
    });
};
function fullPageSlider_es() {
    $('#menu-item-83').attr('data-menuanchor', 'biografia');
    $('#menu-item-84').attr('data-menuanchor', 'referencias');
    $('#menu-item-85').attr('data-menuanchor', 'precios');
    $('#menu-item-86').attr('data-menuanchor', 'contactos');
    $('#fullpage-es').fullpage({
        menu: '#site-navigation',
        anchors: ['home', 'biografia', 'referencias', 'precios', 'contactos']
    });
};
function fullPageSlider_it() {
    $('#menu-item-16').attr('data-menuanchor', 'biografia');
    $('#menu-item-17').attr('data-menuanchor', 'referenze');
    $('#menu-item-18').attr('data-menuanchor', 'prezzi');
    $('#menu-item-19').attr('data-menuanchor', 'contatti');
    $('#fullpage-it').fullpage({
        menu: '#site-navigation',
        anchors: ['home', 'biografia', 'referenze', 'prezzi', 'contatti']
    });
};


$(document).ready(function ($) {
    load_right_language_fullpage()
});
```

I can see in the console that the right plugin is called, but it doesn't work unless the path is equal to "en" (english).

There are also no error in the console.
I'm really stuck with this, so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I found out that the problem is with the url.
If my url is www.mywebsite.com it works properly, if my website is www.mywebsite.com/folder than it doesn't work anymore.
Any idea why?

**EDIT 2**

I solved this. Apparently using intese plugin wasn't a very good idea. It's now working properly as it should. This question can be closed. Thanks

Comment: Always add a reproduction of your problem in jsfiddle or codepen. Make it easy for others to help you and you'll get more answers.

Comment: any idea how to reproduce a wordpress website on fiddle?

Comment: You just need to reproduce the front end, not the whole site...

Comment: ok, but the problem here, the main bit that affects the behaviour, is the polylang plugin. So reproducing the front end won't work cause the plugin won't be there.

Comment: Reproduce the front end of that plugin. Nothing that can not be reproduced in jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: https://github.com/wp-plugins/polylang here's the plugin code...any help on how to reproduce the plugin behaviour on codepen then? Database, different pages to load, different url paths...if you can help me i'd love to reproduce this so that the issue i've got is clearer

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to do it yourself. Not time for it.